# Mejorar visualmente una gráfica en matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, visualización-de-datos

Tengo un código que lee varios dataframes de pandas en Python y los convierte en una gráfica usando matplotlib, quisiera graficar estos dataframes en una sola gráfica para observar su relación, sim embargo, la diferencia de datos entre ambas es tanto que visualmente se ve algo feo. Me gustaría saber si hay algún truco para poder obtener esto con la información actual.

Los CSV se obtienen de los siguientes enlaces, no se ocupa crear nada para descargarlos y se obtiene en el botón al lado de la gráfica para descargarlos:

Casos-positivos-diarios-en-San-Nicolas-de-los-Garza-Promedio-movil-de-7-dias: https://datamexico.org/es/profile/geo/san-nicolas-de-los-garza#covid19-evolucion

Denuncias-segun-bien-afectado-en-San-Nicolas-de-los-GarzaClic-en-el-grafico-para-seleccionar: https://datamexico.org/es/profile/geo/san-nicolas-de-los-garza#seguridad-publica-denuncias

Este es el código que estoy usando:

```
#plotting
plt.plot_date(covid['Month'], covid['Monthly Cases'], '-')
plt.plot_date(her['Month'], her['Value'], '-', color='red')
plt.plot_date(fam['Month'], fam['Value'], '-', color='green')
plt.plot_date(sex['Month'], sex['Value'], '-', color='blue')
plt.plot_date(soc['Month'], soc['Value'], '-', color='yellow')
plt.plot_date(lif['Month'], lif['Value'], '-', color='purple')
plt.plot_date(per['Month'], per['Value'], '-', color='brown')
plt.plot_date(oth['Month'], oth['Value'], '-', color='pink')
#plt.plot_date(comp['Month'], comp['Value'], '-', color='green')
plt.xticks(rotation=25)

plt.legend(['Covid Monthly Cases', 'Heritage Reports', 'Family Reports', 'Sexual Freedom and Safety Reports', 'Society Reports', 'Life and Bodily Integrity Reports', 'Personal Freedom Reports', 'Other Affected Legal Assets (Common Jurisdiction) Reports'])

plt.show()
```

Así se ve la gráfica actualmente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si observamos tus datos vemos que caben en dos grupos: *Reportes* y *Casos Covid*. Así que podrías usar dos *ejes Y* utilizando [subplots de Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html)

```
# plotting
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots() # Generas el primer subplot aquí

ax1.plot_date(her['Month'], her['Value'], '-', color='red')
ax1.plot_date(fam['Month'], fam['Value'], '-', color='green')
ax1.plot_date(sex['Month'], sex['Value'], '-', color='blue')
ax1.plot_date(soc['Month'], soc['Value'], '-', color='yellow')
ax1.plot_date(lif['Month'], lif['Value'], '-', color='purple')
ax1.plot_date(per['Month'], per['Value'], '-', color='brown')
ax1.plot_date(oth['Month'], oth['Value'], '-', color='pink')
#plt.plot_date(comp['Month'], comp['Value'], '-', color='green')
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)
ax1.legend(['Heritage Reports', 'Family Reports', 'Sexual Freedom and Safety Reports', 'Society Reports', 'Life and Bodily Integrity Reports', 'Personal Freedom Reports', 'Other Affected Legal Assets (Common Jurisdiction) Reports'])
ax1.set_ylabel('Reports')

ax2 = ax1.twinx() # Creas un nuevo subplot que comparta el mismo eje X
ax2.plot_date(covid['Month'], covid['Monthly Cases'], '--') # Diferenciamos con línea punteada
ax2.legend(['Covid Cases'])
ax2.set_ylabel('Covid Cases')
```

Y de esta manera del lado izquierdo quedará la escala para tus *Reportes* y del lado derecho para los *Casos Covid*

[image: Gráfica con subplots]

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar escala logarítmica en el eje Y para que no haya tanta diferencia entre las gráficas y se puedan leer mejor (si entiendes cómo leer la escala logarítmica). Y yo pondría la legend fuera, para que no tape las gráficas.

Basta añadir al final de tu código, tras todos los `plt.plot_date()` lo siguiente:

```
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.yscale("log")
plt.legend(['Covid Monthly Cases', 'Heritage Reports', 'Family Reports', 
            'Sexual Freedom and Safety Reports', 'Society Reports', 
            'Life and Bodily Integrity Reports', 'Personal Freedom Reports', 
            'Other Affected Legal Assets (Common Jurisdiction) Reports'],
           bbox_to_anchor=(1., .5), loc="center left")
```

El resultado en este caso se ve así:

[image: Resultado]

**Nota**: He cambiado amarillo por naranja en una de las gráficas. El amarillo se veia muy mal.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por sus sugerencias.